# How to select next sibling of a certain type with JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got some html

```
<h4 id="start-here">title</h4>
<p>paragraph</p>
<p>paragraph</p>
...some number of paragraphs... 
<a href="#" class="link">link</a>
```

And I've got the `<h4>` with the id selected in JavaScript. How do I get from that selection in JS to the first `<a>` which is of the class link, or just the next sibling anchor tag?

Comment: `document.querySelector('#stat-here ~ a')` will return the first anchor sibling

Comment: Yes! You rock. Thank you : )

Comment: @LGSon you should post it as an answer. This is something most beginner JS developer would want to know.

Comment: @YongQuan Okay ... so I did, thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and a CSS selector, here with the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) `~`, you can achieve that like this:

*A side note, in below samples I target inline style, though it is in general better to toggle a class.*

Stack snippet

```js
(function(){

  document.querySelector('#start-here ~ a.link').style.color = 'red';

})();
```

```html
<h4 id="start-here">title</h4>
<p>paragraph</p>
<a href="#">link</a>
<p>paragraph</p>
<a href="#" class="link">link</a>
```

---

Updated based on another question/comment, how to get more than one element in return.

With [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) one can do similar, and target multiple elements like this.

Stack snippet

```js
(function(){

  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#div2, #div3');

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.color = 'red';
  }

})();
```

```html
<h4 id="start-here1">title</h4>
<div id="div1">some text</div>

<h4 id="start-here2">title</h4>
<div id="div2">some text</div>

<h4 id="start-here3">title</h4>
<div id="div3">some text</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

The "start-here" ID on your element makes this easy. But let's imagine you have a reference to a DOM element without such a convenient selector, and you don't want to add a temporary ID to it.

In that case, you could use XPath with [document.evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) and your DOM reference as the second argument. Let's say you have that reference in `yourElement` and you want the next `<section>` sibling

```
const nextSibling = document.evaluate("following-sibling::section", yourElement, null,
  XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE).singleNodeValue
```

Answer (score 3):

I think to start with the first sibling, then i put all the siblings inside an array. Hence I extract what you want.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("stat-here");
console.log(x)
var result = [],
    node = x.nextSibling;

while ( node ) {
    if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE ) {
     result.push( node );
    }
    node = node.nextElementSibling || node.nextSibling;
}
console.log(result, '\n Result: ',result[result.length-2])
```

```html
<h4 id="stat-here">title</h4>
<p>paragraph</p>
<p>paragraph</p>
<a href="#" class="link">link</a>
```

Comment: Answers without explanation generally get downvotes and fewer upvotes.