# getelementbyid Multiple ID display

Tags: javascript, html

I have a drop down where once a subject is clicked it opens selected fields on a list. Is it possible to display two or multiple div's from one click?

Here is my current code;

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         function showfield(name){


 if(name=='Hijacking')document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Registration: 
     <input type="text" name="reg" />' +
            'Make: <input type="text" name="make" /> ' + 'Model: <input 
     type="text" name="model" />';
        else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
        if document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML='Name: <input type="text  
         ="name" />';
        else document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML='';
       }
     </script>

<select name="travel_arriveVia" id="travel_arriveVia" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option selected="selected">Please select ...</option>
    <option value="Hijacking">Hijacking</option>
    <option value="Theft">Theft</option>
    <option value="Overdue Rental">Overdue Rental</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

So I have tried this;

```
if(name=='Hijacking')document.getElementById('div1' 'div2').innerHTML='Registration: <input type="text" name="reg" />' +
                'Make: <input type="text" name="make" /> ' + 'Model: <input type="text" name="model" />';
            else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
```

What my aim is is to have div1 and div2 show when lets say hijacking is selected, the reason is that lets say div 2 has common fields in other selections in my dropdown

Second Attempt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $('select[name="travel_arriveVia"]').change(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "Hijacking"){
            $("#div1, #div2).show();
        }
    });​
</script>

<select name="travel_arriveVia" id="travel_arriveVia" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <option selected="selected">Please select ...</option>
    <option value="Hijacking">Hijacking</option>
    <option value="Theft">Theft</option>
    <option value="Overdue Rental">Overdue Rental</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>

<div class="Hijacking" id="div1" style="display:none;">
    Registration: <input type="text" name="reg" /> Make: <input type="text" name="make" /> Model: <input type="text" name="model" />
</div>
<div class="Hijacking" id="div2" style="display:none;">
    More html
</div>
```

Comment: You can't do `document.getElementById('div1' 'div2')`. With `document.querySelectorAll('#div1, #div2')` you can, and then loop the result with e.g. `for() {}`

Comment: But `div1` and `div2` don't have anything in them? So what is there to show?

Comment: @NickParsons how do you mean they have nothing in them, the els is hidden thus when not selected there is nothing to show. It works perfectly but all I am trying to obtain is by selecting hijacking it should show two div's. On single div the code works.

Comment: I linked to an answer of mine, which I updated to show how you can do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54714370/2827823

Comment: @LGSon That is even confusing me more, as I am not trying to change a color, or div text, I am trying to un-hide text boxes which I am stating in the innerHTML section

Comment: Well, when hiding you use `elements[i].style.display = 'none'` instead of e.g set a color. The linked answer is suppose to show the logic how to select multiple elements, and with the result you can do what ever you want.

Comment: Or e.g. `el.style.display = 'block'` to show a hidden element. And btw, I added `javascript` to your tag list, and if you wan't jQuery, or any other script framework, add those too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using jQuery

As a reference: https://jquery.com/

You could change your code using jQuery.

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/8a20rkwt/

In your head section include jquery like so:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then use it like so to show multiple elements by id with one click:

```
<script>
 $(function() {

    $('#travel_arriveVia').change(function(){
        $(".Hijacking").hide();
        if ($(this).val() == "Hijacking"){
            $("#div1, #div2").show();
        }
    });

  });
</script>
```

In your html:

```
 <select name="travel_arriveVia" id="travel_arriveVia">
    <option selected="selected">Please select ...</option>
    <option value="Hijacking">Hijacking</option>
    <option value="Theft">Theft</option>
    <option value="Overdue Rental">Overdue Rental</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>

<div class="Hijacking" id="div1" style="display:none;">
    Registration: <input type="text" name="reg" /> Make: <input type="text" name="make" /> Model: <input type="text" name="model" />
</div>
<div class="Hijacking" id="div2" style="display:none;">
    More html
</div>
```

More details about the jQuery change event handler are here: https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: I have added second attempt code. The onclick should triger the action I am not sure where to point that to from my drop down

Comment: I have edited my code exactly as yours when I select Hijacking nothing is shown

Comment: @JamesWright please take a look at the updated code and also fiddler link: https://jsfiddle.net/8a20rkwt/

Comment: Great that worked, I also added for each option own DIV and they all pulling thru